# Adding a method to Bluebird promise

Tags: promise, bluebird

I have promisified Mongoose. I have some methods that extent Mongoose Query that now would need to be added to Bluebird. I don't mind extending Mongoose but do not want to take the same approach for this more gobal library. Looking through the docs I see some potentials but I am not sure.

I would like to come as close/clean as the following:

```
Model.findAsync().toCustom();
```

`toCustom` is basically a form of toJSON which 1) execs the query and 2) custom outputs the results/create custom errors etc... pretty straighforward.

What is the cleanest way to achieve something like the above?  I would like to avoid doing this each time:

```
Model.findAsync().then(function(docs) {
  return toCustom(docs);
}, function(err) {
  return toCustom(err);
});
```

You get the idea...

Comment: But you could just do `.then(toCustom, toCustom)`? (Though I don't think it's a good idea to call `toCustom` on *all* errors)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bluebird actually supports your use case directly. If you need to publish a library that extends bluebird in your own custom way you can get a fresh copy of bluebird by doing:

```
var Promise = require("bluebird/js/main/promise")();
Promise.promisifyAll(require("mongoose")); // promisify with a local copy
Promise.prototype.toCustom = function(){
   return this.then(toCustom, toCustom); // assuming this isn't just `.finally`
};
```

You might also want to export it somehow. This feature is designed for library authors and for getting an isolated copy of bluebird. See the [for library authors](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird#for-library-authors) section in the wiki.